# how to deform an image deforming the coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to see how an image get deformed if I know how its coordinates are deformed.

for example: here I draw a circle

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *

plane_side = 500.0 #arcsec

y_l, x_l, = np.mgrid[-plane_side:plane_side:1000j, -plane_side:plane_side:1000j]

r = np.sqrt(y_l**2 + x_l**2)

indexes1 = np.where(r<150.0)
indexes2 = np.where(r>160.0)

image = r.copy()
image[:,:] = 1.0
image[indexes1] = 0.0
image[indexes2] = 0.0

imgplot = plt.imshow(image,cmap="rainbow")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

If I want to deform the coordinates like this:

```
y_c = y_lense**3
x_c = x_lense**2
```

and plot the image distorted, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plt.pcolormesh()`:

```
y_c = (y_l/plane_side)**3
x_c = (x_l/plane_side)**2

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.pcolormesh(x_c, y_c, image, cmap="rainbow")
ax.set_xlim(0, 0.2)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 0.1);
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: This isn't a great solution if you want your output to be an image, but certainly is a quick way to visualize it

Comment: Note that pcolormesh takes the corners of the pixels not the centers as its positions, so `image[:,-1]` and `image[-1,:]` are being discarded

Answer (score 1):

In general (without using a dedicated library), you should apply an inverse transformation to the coordinates of the new image. Than, you interpolate values from the original image at the calculated coordinates.

For example, if you want to apply the following transformation:

```
x_new = x**2
y_new = y**2
```

you would do something like that:

```
import numpy as np
# some random image
image = np.random.rand(10,10)

# new interpolated image - actually not interpolated yet :p
# TODO: in some cases, this image should be bigger than the original image. You can calculate optimal size from the original image considering the transformation used.
image_new = np.zeros(image.shape)

# get the coordinates
x_new, y_new = np.meshgrid( range(0,image_new.shape[1]), range(0,image_new.shape[0]) )
x_new = np.reshape(x_new, x_new.size) 
y_new = np.reshape(y_new, y_new.size) 

# do the inverse transformation
x = np.sqrt(x_new)
y = np.sqrt(y_new)

# TODO: here you should check that all x, y coordinates fall inside the image borders

# do the interpolation. The simplest one is nearest neighbour interpolation. For better image quality, bilinear interpolation should be used.
image_new[y_new,x_new] = image[np.round(y).astype(np.int) , np.round(x).astype(np.int)]
```

Comment: `scipy.ndimage` may help here